# How to fix Debian's NetworkManager with question mark even though network is working?

Tags: kali-linux, networkmanager

I have an up-to-date Kali Linux 2018.2 with `open-vm-tools` installed on an up-to-date VMware Workstation Pro 14.

It's working as expected, but there's a little bug that I'd like to fix, the NetworkManager question mark and lack of Ethernet configuration inside 'Settings → Network', as seen in the image below.

[image: kali]

My network is fully working, I can ping LAN and WAN, can resolve IP's and hostnames etc. So, I don't know why I'm getting this behavior. My VMware network settings are as follows:

[image: vmware settings]

Comment: It's likely b/c this is a Kali Linux Q, don't read so much into it, work your problem and you'll get good results.

Comment: If you have to ask about Kali here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me. But as I stated, work your issue and ignore that, if you're truly trying to help yourself, others will help.

Comment: See here for your Q about the question mark - https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/110773/f26-gnome-324-wifi-icon-shows-as-a-question-mark/

Comment: Why is this tagged Debian if you're talking about Kali?

Comment: @roaima because it is a DEBIAN based distro, Kali is nothing special. https://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian

Comment: @slm why it should be an issue to ask about Kali Linux, it is just another Debian distro and it even have a proper tag here on the site. I use it for work, I have been using it for some years now and just recently this icon appeared and I never changed a thing on network settings.

Comment: @JChris the link says it all about Kali. That's the end of the converdtion about why. Focus on your question..

Comment: "it is just another Debian distro". NO! The Debian Tag says "Questions specific to the Debian official distribution (stable, testing, or unstable); if you are using a derivative of Debian (e.g. Mint, Ubuntu, Kali, etc), then use that distribution’s tag instead." "Something to be aware of: Debian is a core or source distribution. This means there are many Debian-based distributions. THEY ARE NOT DEBIAN. Their information may or may not be useful or safely applied to Debian. Debian has no way of knowing what has been changed on these systems. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue using `ifupdown`, but display it correctly on Gnome GUI you need to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and change `managed=false` to `managed=true` for the `[ifupdown]` section.

[image]

After that restart `NetworkManager` with `systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

[image]

Comment: That doesn’t quite allow you to “continue using `ifupdown`”, it tells Network Manager to manage interfaces listed in `/etc/network/interfaces`. See `man NetworkManager.conf` for details. (So `ifupdown` will set the interfaces up following `/etc/network/interfaces`, and then Network Manager will take them over and set them up as it sees fit.)

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is displayed because Network Manager isn’t managing your connection; presumably, `ifupdown` is: look at the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`, if it has lines describing `eth0` or `enp0...`, that’s the reason.

You can either ignore the question mark, or if you want Network Manager to manage your connection, run `ifdown eth0` (replacing `eth0` as appropriate), delete the corresponding entries in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and configure Network Manager.

See [the networking chapter](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html) in the Debian Reference for details.

Comment: Actually, I found the "issue". I'm still using `ifupdown`, but now the  `NetworkManager` plugin recognizes that I'm using it, see the solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459097/95396).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Debian 12 and restarting Network Manager removes the question mark. You can add it as a cronjob, at startup, with some delay.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add the following line:

```
@reboot sleep 30 && systemctl restart NetworkManager
```